# Search Engine - finding a value in a txtbox in an excel sheet and writing data

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first post on here and perhaps a difficult one.

I am creating a scheduling tool for a friend for their clinic of therapists.

I have a form entitled frmschedule that when the user selects the date and time it will find the match on an excel sheet and write the data such as name etc.

The user will select a date from a preloaded listbox (lstboxdate) stating from January 1 2017 to December 31st 2017.

The user will then select a time from a preloaded listbox (lstboxtime) stating 8:00 / 8:20 / 8:40 / 9:00 etc.

I have a excel spreadhseet that has all 365 days in a list and have given each day a "serial number"  for example January 1st will be "1"

I also have a range with all the times listed and a serial number for each time slot. For eample 8:00 would be 800

After the user has selected the date and time, a "serial number" will be created for that date and time - for example an appointment on January 1 2017 at 8:00 would return a serial number of 1800.  The appointment serial number is stored in a textbox that combines the values of the date serial number along with the time serial number.

When the user selects a command button, I would like vba to find that specific serial number on my schedule spreadsheet (which already has the date/time serial numberfor every day and time) and write the data from txtname / txtphone.

Is there anyone who can help me or have I made this too complicated.

I am not familiar with looping and search engines but have tried to find solutions

thanks in advance

Comment: If you know the date and the time and the number of time slots you have per day then you should be able to calculate the row number without doing a search. Appointment date - Jan 1st gets the number of day minus 1 and multiply by number of time slots per day and add timeslot selected should give you the row number on your sheet. Use cells() to reference the cell you want to update. Or you can lookup range find function in excel VBA.

Comment: Your project sounds complicated.  I'd be interested to know what you think of this Appointment tracker http://www.scotlang.com/AppointmentTracker.xlsx that I made a while ago without using any VBA or forms.  It may at least show you an alternative way to record your appointment data.

Comment: Gordon, really like what you have put together there..My plans were to include the weekly view just like yours but have yet to get to that point..  As for your suggestion I think that is a great idea but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're writing to the sheet with the serial number or displaying the data on the form -- if the latter, a really simple solution is to use a vlookup or index/match.  For example let's say the command button is called CommandButton1, use a click event to lookup your serial number from a different page and return the name/phone combo.

Assumptions: 
Textbox is called TextBox1
Command button=CommandButton1
Serial number with name/phone is on Sheet2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sName$, sPhone$
sName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B100"), 2, False)
sPhone = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C100"), 3, False)
Me.TextBox1 = "Name: " & sName & vbCrLf & "Phone: " & sPhone
End Sub
```

Comment: I think he wants to write to the sheet next to the cell that matches his serial number in order to record the appointment.

Comment: Hello, yes I want to write the data to the excel sheet based on the serial number of the appointment matching on the userform to the excel spreasheet.

Comment: If it helps to realize what exactly needs to be done I have placed the file in dropbox..https://app.box.com/s/2tr5uy269mdcb9rl4d46f73q2d9ldqgn.

Comment: If I am asking too much, my sincere apologies

Answer (score 0):

If you're combo box has the serial number and you're writing to the schedule sheet, you could try something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rngName As Range
Dim rngPhone As Range
Dim i As Integer

i = WorksheetFunction.Match(cint(Me.cboSerial), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A100"), True)

Set rngName = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2)
Set rngPhone = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3)

rngName = Me.txtName
rngPhone = Me.txtNumber
End Sub
```

Basically you're running a Match() worksheet function to return the cell address where your serial number is stored, then you're writing to cells in the same row.

cboSerial is the combo box that stores your serial number
  txtName is the name of the appointment holder
  txtNumber is the phone number of the appointment holder

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have placed your code along with a confirmation dialogue box code in the command button.  I don't get any errors but nothing writes to the excel sheet?  could it be the excel serial numbers are not the same format as the userform serial numbers?

Comment: Ryan, I have reviewed the code and can not find the reason why there was no action to me selecting the command button.

Comment: Sorry, keep hitting enter to move down a line.  I have placed the file on dropbox as I cant place the code here due to length of characters.  Again, thank you                                                                                                               https://app.box.com/s/soca9h0bvt0pqrjpyfzorrdtqeqlfb4w

Comment: I think it might be likely that the numbers in your text box are actually text, but your field running the match function is a number, therefore no match is found. Can you try to convert the value in your text box to an integer?  E.g Cint(me.cboSerial)

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I have taken the above suggestion and added it to the code where the date and time serial number are joined but getting a error message stating requires identifier.  Where would or how would I change the serial number to an interger?                                               Cint(Me.txtserial1.Value) = txtdate1serial.Value & txttime1serial.Value                                                                                     Again thanks for your help...I am learning from this

Comment: I'm writing this from my phone so can't test this, but I've updated my answer to reflect where it should go. If you don't have any luck here I will look into it further in the morning.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. No luck with this and have attempted formatting the data in the spreadsheet as well.

Comment: Hi @SteveClark, I've verified the code works in my test.  Can you verify that your entry form contains the equivalent of txtName and txtNumber and these are being filled out prior to submitting?  I see in your comments above you potentially have a txtserial1 and txtdate1serial fields.  Where I'm using cboSerial you should be using your field than passes the serial number (e.g. January 1 at 8am=1800).